# Alternative to using VIEWS on vendor sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view, vendor

I have a vendor SQL Server 2008 db which I am trying to add-on to with additional tables etc. to customize for my order processing .Net 3.5 site. The vendor db should not be altered. However I need to record the current Order Status which is not included in the vendor's db.

Currently I'm using a VIEW with a CASE to get the Status based on data in the Orders table. To improve performance I'd like to create a new Status table with OrderID & Current_Status.

To keep the Status table up-to-date is there an alternative to frequently running a script which will look at all Orders and update the Status table accordingly?

Comment: Define what you mean by `The vendor db should not be altered.`  Adding a view or a table is altering the database, yet you *do* allow those two options.  Can you add triggers to the vendor's tables?  Are the vendor's tables populated through stored procedures, and can you alter those stored procedures?

Comment: What I mean is the vendor tables and stored proc's (used for insert) should not be altered, and neither should triggers be added to these tables. However adding additional tables, views etc is ok. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a job or other polling-type solution is probably fine if the load imposed by the query is not high and if you can tolerate some delay before the data is synched.

If you can tolerate at least some delay, but the query to check the table is extensive, or if you have several tables you want to perform this operation on, you could also use [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), since you have SQL Server 2008.

[Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx) on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SSIS job to check orders and update the status table. And schedule it to run hourly/daily(as per your requirement). Creating SSIS jobs will not affect any of your vender process or objects.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Should I expect a big performance hit on the db with an SSIS job running every 30 mins and scanning the date_modified field of thousands of rows in the orders table to determine what needs to be updated in the status table?

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your worry, how about an indexed view?

Comment: I'm currently using an indexed view which is proving very inefficient due to the complexity of the CASE statement being used to determine the status each time the user views an order. Hence my reason for storing the status in a table own its own.

Comment: But that's the thing with indexed views; the server "materializes" the view and makes it more or less like a table. Which is to say that it stores the view physically. Just to be clear, you've done "create index" against your view and it's still slow?